# JOptionPane not reading the string

Tags: java, string, swing

I am trying to use the value of a String obtained through JOptionPane. However, there is a problem with reading the String. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class convertNumber123 {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            String numsystem1;
            numsystem1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the numeral system that you want to convert from: binary, octal, decimal or hexadecimal."); 
            if (numsystem1 == "Binary" || numsystem1 == "Octal" || numsystem1 == "Decimal" || numsystem1 == "Hexadecimal")
                System.out.println (numsystem1 + "it is!");
            else 
                System.out.println ("Please, enter the correct system name.");
        }
}
```

Comment: Your question will be closed soon... But you can't compare Strings with `==` you must use the `.equals()` method. So like this... `numsystem1.equalsIgnoreCase("Binary") || ....`

Comment: Thanks a lot, my friend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are comparing strings is wrong. In java you have to use the `.equals()` method like this

```
if (numsystem1.equals("Binary") || numsystem1.equals("Octal") || numsystem1.equals("Decimal") || numsystem1.equals("Hexadecimal"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, I was using `==` instead of `equals()` method. That was the problem.